# Subclass from a class decorated by a class

Tags: python, decorator

I have a decorator, a class decorated by that decorator, and a subclass:

```
def decorated_by_function(cls):
    return cls

@decorated_by_function
class F(object):
    pass

class G(F):
    pass
```

No problem there.

Now, I change the decorator's implementation to be class-based:

```
class decorated_by_class(object):
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self._cls = cls

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._cls(*args, **kwargs)

@decorated_by_class
class C(object):
    pass

class D(C):
    pass
```

And Python gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "h.py", line 23, in <module>
    class D(C):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Edit:

@donkopotamus has given a partial answer below, that `C` is an instance instead of a class. That is why `C` cannot be subclassed. I understand that. My question is: **Is it possible to keep the class-based approach, while also allowing the decorated class to be subclassed?**

The advantage of using a class is that it can be extended. Imagine a decorator with more complicated logic. What is a natural way to modify some of its behavior, but retains most of the logic? Using a class-based approach enables a tree of similar decorators with slightly different functionalities. That is why I want to investigate the possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case

```
@decorated_by_class
class C(object): 
    pass
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
class C(object):
    pass

C = decorated_by_class(C)
```

So in this case `C` is now **an instance** of the class `decorated_by_class` ... it is not a class itself.  Hence, you cannot create another class `D` inheriting from `C`.

I believe what you're probably really wanting to do is use an *instance* of a class as a decorator, for example:

```
class decorated_by_class(object):
    def __init__(self, *some_decorator_args):
        self.args = some_decorator_args

    def compute_something(self):
        return self.args

    def __call__(self, cls):
        # do something with the class
        cls.decorated_with_args = self.compute_something()
        return cls

@decorated_by_class("hello")
class C(object): 
    pass

print(C.decorated_with_args)    # => ('hello',)

class decorated_by_subclass(decorated_by_class):
    def compute_something(self):
        return self.args * 2

@decorated_by_subclass("hello")
class D(object): 
    pass

print(D.decorated_with_args)    # => ('hello', 'hello')
```

Comment: Does it mean, there is *no way* to inherit from `C` if the decorator is implemented in the class-based fashion?

Comment: @NickLee Your decorator is not creating a class when called, if you want to be able to inherit from `C`, it must create a class, not an instance.    Why do you need your decorator itself to be modelled as a class?

Comment: If your decorator *must* itself be a class, then use a metaclass that overrides `__call__` to avoid an instance being created, I won't give an example as its unclear exactly *why* you want to be able to do this ...

Comment: The advantage of a class is that it can be extended and have some methods overriden. Imagine a decorator with more complicated logic. What is a natural way to modify some of its behavior, but retains most of the logic? Using a class-based approach enables a tree of similar decorators with slightly different functionalities. @donkopotamus, it's ok if you can't give an example. I am not asking for examples per se. I believe the question has practical consequences. But at the same time, it is also for my own enlightenment, to know whether something is possible or not.

Comment: @NickLee I'd disagree ... that's not an argument for your decorator being a class.  It's an argument for the *type* of your decorator to be a class.  I've added an example to show what I mean.

Comment: Thank you. Although what I want is more like `cls.decorated_with_args = self.compute_something` (without `()`), your example does illustrate the point.

Comment: And yes, it's an argument for the *type* of my decorator to be a class. I wasn't totally careful with my wording. Thanks for pointing it out.